# Jquery hover unbind and binding again

Tags: jquery, hover, bind, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm currently using this bit of Jquery.

```
$(".option5").toggle(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("red"),
    $("#check5").attr('checked',true),
    $(".option5").unbind('mouseenter');
  },
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("red"),
    $("#check5").attr('checked',false),
});
```

In the first function i have added an .unbind of mouseenter, which does exactly what i need it to, but in the next function, what do i put to bind the hover (mouseenter mouseleave) back into the function. Ive tried a few options but wont go back to the hover function i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".option5").bind("refreshMouseEnter", function(event){
  $(this).mouseenter(function(event){
    //do your work
  });
}).bind("refreshMouseLeave", function(event){
  $(this).mouseleave(function(event){
   //do your work
  });
}).toggle(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("red"),
    $("#check5").attr('checked',true),
    $(".option5").unbind('mouseenter');
  },
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("red"),
    $("#check5").attr('checked',false),
///be very sure you want this selector!!! i just copied from above...
    $(".option5").trigger('refreshMouseEnter');
}).trigger("refreshMouseEnter").trigger("refreshMouseLeave");
});
```